# Set custom Typeface to Textview in java android

Tags: java, android, fonts

I'm trying to change the default font to a custom font (handa.ttf).

I have located the file **handa.ttf** in path:

```
MyProject/app/src/main/assets/fonts/handa.ttf
```

I defined my type face in java programmatically like this :

```
Typeface tp1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/handa.ttf");
logo1t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.log1text);
logo2t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.log2text);
logo2t.setTypeface(tp1);
```

I have no error in my code but when I run my app no changes happen! Font remains default!

I think I have no mistakes in my XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#fffaf0"
    android:gravity="center">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/mainiconimage"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"/> 
<LinearLayout
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mainiconimage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
android:text="High"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/log1text"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textColor="#880000ff"/>
<TextView
android:text="Skill"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/log2text"
android:padding="4dp"
android:background="@drawable/textbg"
android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What is the wrong !

Comment: Instead of giving font programmatically, try to give font in xml. I hope it'll work.

Comment: I tried to do this but when I add "font" folder it gives me an error :/

Answer (score 0):

Just add a font folder inside the res folder ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGPWs.png)).
You can than just set the font in the xml file like this

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/your_font_here"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textColor="@color/some_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: I did that but I got Error "invalid resource directory " although I had refreshed the project!

Comment: @karamE could you post your error messages so we can see what the exact message is?

Comment: It says : "aapt: invalid resource directory name: /storage/emulated/0/AppProjects/a/app/src/main/res font"!

Comment: Then I got error that " Unknown entity 'R'"